# Передача текста

Tags: javascript, html

Знания JS на уровне ученика. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать имя ссылки в текстовую форму?
Более подробное описание:
Форма:    
Ссылки:
    Name1
    Name2
    Name3
Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на определенную ссылку, её название было помещенно в форму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link'),
  input = document.querySelector('.textInput');


for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = this.innerText;
    return false;
  }, false);
}
```

```css
a,
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>
<input type="text" class="textInput" />
```